# How to check if there is another uiimage (with the same name) in the bundle?

Tags: ios, uiimage, bundle

Question is in the title, how do I check to see if there is another image in the bundle with the same name?

Comment: This will cause an XCode build warning, you could tell by that.  By the time your project is built there should be no duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but I'm adding images to my Bundle programmatically, and I'm assuming it will crash if I try and add a image that is already there with the same name.

Comment: You can't add things to bundles at runtime...You can only put files in your sandbox...is that what you mean?

Comment: May I have the code how to add files in the bundle.

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi There is no code to add files into the bundle.  Files are added to the main bundle when you include them in your xcode project--ie., right click on the project folders inside XCode, Add Existing Files to your project, and then build. If you want to save files to the device at runtime, that's another question entirely--the bundle cannot be edited at runtime.  You'd need to save the files to documents or somewhere similar (this is an operation that requires code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I know, there is no way to check for duplicate images with the same name in your documents folder. So I decided just to make a manager class for the images that I add to the doc folder and keep track of everything that way.